# Helping people Vs People helping

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, gerunds

If i want to say:

> - **Helping people** is a proof of being kind-hearted
> - **People helping** is a proof of being kind-hearted

Don’t these two sentences give the same exact meaning?

More examples:

> - **Studying English** is complicated.
> - **English studying** is complicated .

Comment: The meaning may not change, but the first form is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the phrase ***studying English***, *English* is the object of the gerund *studying*.

In the phrase ***English studying***, *English* is an **attributive noun** of the gerund *studying*.

The first means the studying of English, presumably meaning the language. The second means studying in an English manner, whatever you might think that means.

Likewise, ***helping people*** has *people* as the object of the gerund *helping*. The sentence as a whole means that a person who helps people is proven to be kind-hearted.

Now, ***people helping*** could be read in two ways. You *could* read it with *people* as an attributive noun, which would most likely make it near enough synonymous with *helping people*. I wouldn't expect it to be read that way, and if I wanted people to read it that way, I would hyphenate it as *people-helping*. Well, I wouldn't, because I would write it in another way, but if I had to use those words in that order to have that effect, I would hyphenate it. Come to think of it, if you hyphenated in the other example, to make *English-studying*, it might tend to be read as what you are saying it should mean. In both cases, though, it would be weird, not idiomatic, and frankly verging on unnatural.

The more usual way to read it would be that the *people* are the *subject* of the verb. It would then mean *the fact that people help is a proof of...*, which then wouldn't make sense with *...being kind-hearted*, but would make sense with *...kind-heartedness*. That would then mean that the fact that people do help each other indicates that there is such a thing as people being kind-hearted.

So, no, in neither case does it mean the same thing when you swap the word order. It changes the parsing, and will change the meaning in most cases. **Word order *matters*.**

Comment: As far as i am concerned, if not mistaken, that gerund can be modified by an adverb but not attributive noun!